# MYSQL list of dates for nth day of month between dates

Tags: mysql

Need help with SQL statement that will return a list of dates based on the following conditions:

The nth day of every month.

I have the following statement that returns a list of dates based on a recurring pattern that has start and end dates, recurrence (eg every x weeks), and the week day.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `GETEVERYOTHERDATE`(IN _START DATE, IN _END DATE, IN _REC INT(5), IN _DAY VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN

SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8';

select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) DATES from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where DATES between _START and _END
and dayname(DATES) = _DAY
AND WEEK(DATES) % _REC = WEEK(_START) % _REC;


END
```

So if the conditions are:

```
START = 2019-01-01
END = 2019-06-30
DAY = FIRST TUESDAY
RECURRENCE = every month
```

The results would be:

```
2019-01-01
2019-02-05
2019-03-05
2019-04-02
2019-05-07
2019-06-04
```

So I haven't been able to come up with the proper where clause. Perhaps I am totally wrong in my approach.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: the first Tuesday of a month has to be one of the first seven days in the month.

The numeric day of month value is guaranteed to be between 1 and 7. We can evaluate that with `DAYOFMONTH(t.foo)` or `DAY(t.foo)`.

Also, `DAYOFWEEK(t.foo)` will return `3` for a Tuesday.

Or we can use `DAYNAME(t.foo)` if we want to evaluate to a string (if we are going to handle national language differences, 'Tuesday' vs. 'Dienstag' vs. 'Mardi', et al.

---

If I needed to restrict date or datetime values of `foo` to "first Tuesday in a month", I'd do this:

```
  WHERE DAYOFMONTH(t.foo) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 
    AND DAYOFWEEK(t.foo) = 3
```